# Building an array of objects with values from a HashMap

Tags: java

I was given an assignment to build a Huffman Tree to encode strings from a file for my Data Structures class but I am having a bit of trouble. I know how to build the tree and encode the values but I need to build an array of nodes to that will then be put into a sorted list.
I wrote a for loop that iterates over the length of the array of nodes and nested a foreach loop that iterates over the HashMap. The problem lies within creating each new node for each character. My code doesn't seem to add all the values to the array and I have tried multiple different loops but they all produce similar results. I had an idea of creating two arrays, one for the key and one for the values, that I could pass in to the node constructor but that doesn't really work.

Here is the class for the nodes:

```
public class HuffmanTreeNode {
    public char key;
    public int value;
    public HuffmanTreeNode nextNode = null;
    public HuffmanTreeNode leftChild = null;
    public HuffmanTreeNode rightChild = null;

    public HuffmanTreeNode(char k, int v) {
        key = k;
        value = v;
    }

    public HuffmanTreeNode(HuffmanTreeNode left, HuffmanTreeNode right) {
        leftChild = left;
        rightChild = right;

        value = rightChild.value + leftChild.value;
    }

    public boolean isLeaf() {
        if (leftChild == null && rightChild == null) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the code for building the array of nodes:

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (String s : fileContents) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            Integer value = frequencies.get(new Character(c));

            if (value != null) {
                frequencies.put(c, new Integer(value + 1));
            } else {
                frequencies.put(c, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    char[] chars = new char[frequencies.size()];
    int[] freq = new int[frequencies.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < frequencies.size(); i++) {
        for (HashMap.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : frequencies.entrySet()) {
            chars[i] = entry.getKey();
            freq[i] = entry.getValue();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < frequencies.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(chars[i] + " " + freq[i]);
    }


    SortedList sortedList = new SortedList();
    HuffmanTreeNode[] nodes = new HuffmanTreeNode[frequencies.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        nodes[i] = new HuffmanTreeNode(chars[i], freq[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Could you clarify the question a bit more with some example input and expected output.

Comment: So my example input is an array of Strings that contains the content of the file being read (fileContents). In the file are the lines Hello/how/are you (the '/' indicate a new line - 3 lines in total). The output I need to get is each character and the number of times they appear, which is already in the HashMap. I just don't think im iterating right because my output is the same character and frequency at each index.

Comment: Please don't give your instance fields public access.

Comment: I switched them for testing something when I first started writing the program and I forgot to switch it back

Answer (score 0):

I actually just fixed my code by changing the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < frequencies.size(); i++) {
    for (HashMap.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : frequencies.entrySet()) {
        chars[i] = entry.getKey();
        freq[i] = entry.getValue();
    }
}
```

to:

```
int index = 0;
    for (HashMap.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : frequencies.entrySet()) {
        chars[index] = entry.getKey();
        freq[index] = entry.getValue();
        index++;
    }
```